# How do I print an "x" shape?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, scanf

I needed some help with my homework. I've spent about 2 hours on this but I can't get my head around it (c programming). I have to print an x like so:

```
*       *
 *     * 
  *   *  
   * *   
    *    
   * *   
  *   *  
 *     * 
*       *
```

The steps of the program should work like this.
1. User inputs a single number which is the size (this single number is basically the width and height). Also we can assume the user always puts an odd number (so we don't need conditions for that).
2. It draws the X in respect to that size.

However, I can only use while loops, and if statements, scanf and printf. Nothing else.

This is what I can get so far (just a diagonal)

```
row = 0;
while (row < size) {
    column = 0;
    while (column < size) {
        if (row == column) {
            printf("*");
        } else {
            printf(" ");
        }
        column++;;
    }
    printf("\n");
    row++;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to add the unsuccessful code so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: It's all about finding a relationship between an index in a line, and what it should contain. If you've spent 2 hours on this, and haven't doodled anything on paper to get a "feel for it", you haven't attacked the problem properly yet.

Comment: Please describe what you did try to do and where was the problem

Comment: @PazO I edited the question. That's what I came up with.. I don't know what to do after...

Comment: @machine_1 Fixed it

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried on paper (actually the first thing I did). Only relationship I can find is just making a diagonal, I don't know how to make 2 diagonals (to make the X)

Comment: sorry I didn't notice you coudn't use for loops,I'll redo it using while loops only

Comment: @AlessandroMessori Yea, I haven't learnt for, I don't know what it is

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size, row, column;

    scanf("%d", &size);

    row = 0;
    while (row < size)
    {
        column = 0;
        while (column < size)
        {
            if (column == row || column == size - row - 1)
            {
                printf("x");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            column++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        row++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is for? I haven't learnt that yet. I only know while, if statement, printf and scanf.

Comment: for is a loop very similar to while, except that you specify a counter and a, a exit condition and how to update the counter at every iteration of the loop. You will surely study it in your course, is a basic feature of every programming language

Comment: I edited my post so that it works using only the functions and loops you have done so far

Comment: @JoeyYue `for (exp1; exp2; exp3) body ~ exp1; while (exp2) { body; exp3; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int size = 11; //this should be the size given by user.

    char line[size + 1];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) line[i] = ' ';
    line[size] = '\0';

    int se = 0;
    int sw = size - 1;
    while(se < size && sw >= 0){
        line[se] = line[sw] = 'x';
        printf("%s\n", line);
        line[se++] = line[sw--] = ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on Ideone and worked.

Comment: But the question says user will enter an odd number: "1. User inputs a single number which is the size (this single number is basically the width and height). Also we can assume the user always puts an odd number (so we don't need conditions for that)."

Answer (score 0):

You are checking only one diagonal.To get the required pattern ,change the if condition as follows...
if ((row == column)||(row==(size-column-1)))